# Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka binder and how to queue data from source

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I'm a newbie to spring cloud stream with kafka and wondering something about the concept of it. In my application, when the source sends a message to kafka binder streamingly, data doesn't pile up ... I can see data source is working in Kafka consumer which is not actually consume, just for checking out that data really comes out.

However, the thing is I couldn't consume data piled at the receiver.(the listener of processor). It can consume only the data streamed from source in near real time.

Let me give you an example.
For producer,

```
data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, ... (streaming for producer)
```

For consumer, it would be started when data4 is producing. Then, my application would get data from data 4...

```
data4, data5, data6, .... (streaming for consumer)
```

As I know the concept of Kafka, data1, data2, data3 should be waiting for a consumer but it doesn't for me. What do I know something wrong and any idea about to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show your configuration.

Anonymous consumers (those without a `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.xxx.group`) start consuming from the end of the topic (at the time that they are started), so will likely "miss" some messages.

Consumers with a `group` (that have never consumed) start at the beginning; consumers with a `group`(that have previously consumed) start from where they left off.

Comment: This is so clear and I just searched for what a group means in Kafka. You made my day. Thank you so much. To give some information for people struggling with it like me, data can be outbounded once you add a group in the same channel. I recommend you to use group even if you have just one topic and one consumer. Cheers!